# java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol : /site/dispatcher.jsp?url=https://somesite.com/some-url

Tags: java, jsp, jboss, weblogic

I am trying to redirect the page to base URL after logging it off. I am using below code for it

```
res.sendRedirect("/site/dispatcher.jsp?url=" + url);
```

where url is the bas URL to which the page should be redirected. This had been working fine on Jboss7 as of now, but when the same is delpoyed in WebLogic it does not work fine. I receive below exception :

java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol : /site/dispatcher.jsp?url=https://somesite.com/some-url

Below is the configuration in weblogic.xml :

```
<container-descriptor>

    <show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</show-archived-real-path-enabled>

    <redirect-with-absolute-url>false</redirect-with-absolute-url>

</container-descriptor>
```

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path URL just to test? I mean as the redirect to the `dispatcher.jsp` resource, not the value of the `url` parameter. Since it's complaining about missing protocol.

Comment: Also have a look at the deployment description flag `redirect-with-absolute-url` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs70/webapp/weblogic_xml.html), maybe that'll help?

Comment: Do you have space in URL?

Comment: @user7294900 : no there is no space in URL

Comment: @Mena : that is not set explicitly, will set it to false and check

Comment: @Mena : I have tried with the suggested parameter as below   <container-descriptor>

    <show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</show-archived-real-path-enabled>

    <redirect-with-absolute-url>false</redirect-with-absolute-url>

</container-descriptor>

Comment: @TinyJaguar and... no luck?

Comment: @Mena : yes did not work. I have edited the question too according to the latest changes made.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue on weblogic 12.2.1.3 , does anybody have any solution ?